# ansible list dict keys and subkeys

Tags: ansible

I wonder if anyone can help. I have some data which I would like to get each *dest* key and *dest* subkey to pass into a Jinja2 template

```yaml
    blob: {
       'TEST': {
            'source': [
              '1.2.3.4'
            ],
            'dest': {
                'john': {
                  'x.x.x.x',    
                },
                'barry': {
                  'y.y.y.y'
                }
            }   
        }       
    }`
```

---

In YAML

```yaml
    blob:
      TEST:
        dest:
          barry: {y.y.y.y: null}
          john: {x.x.x.x: null}
        source: [1.2.3.4]
```

---

I would like a get keys of *blob* and keys of *blob.TEST.dest* essentially:

```py
for i in blob.keys():
    for s in blob[i.dest.keys()]
```

I need *i* and *s* to create a file name. I have tried to use *with_subelements*, but failed.

Output could be something like:

```yaml
key: TEST  subkey: john
key: TEST  subkey: barry
```

Can someone advise if something like the below is possible:

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "key: {{ item.0 }} subkey: {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ blob.keys() }}"
        - "{{ blob.[item.0]['dest'].keys() }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary of the keys' list(s)

```yaml
  blob_keys: "{{ dict(blob|
                      dict2items|
                      json_query('[].[key, keys(value.dest)]')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  blob_keys:
    TEST: [barry, john]
```

Iterate this dictionary with subelements

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "key: {{ item.0.key }} subkey: {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ blob_keys|dict2items|subelements('value') }}"
```

gives abridged

```yaml
  msg: 'key: TEST subkey: barry'
  msg: 'key: TEST subkey: john'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    blob:
      TEST:
        dest:
          barry: {y.y.y.y: null}
          john: {x.x.x.x: null}
        source: [1.2.3.4]

    blob_keys: "{{ dict(blob|
                        dict2items|
                        json_query('[].[key, keys(value.dest)]')) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: blob_keys

    - debug:
        msg: "key: {{ item.0.key }} subkey: {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ blob_keys|dict2items|subelements('value') }}"
```